# What's the difference between a standard INNER JOIN and an INNER JOIN of an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone please explain the difference between this:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON ...
INNER JOIN C ON ...
```

And this:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B INNER JOIN C ON ... ON ...
```

Example:

```
SELECT A.Something, B.Something, C.Something
INTO #TempTable
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    INNER JOIN TableC C ON C.FK = B.PK
ON A.JoinField = B.ID
```

Comment: Please test once before you submit any query.  There isn't anything to say more than `first is valid and second is invalid join`.

Comment: @Susang - both are valid

Comment: Notice, that you can join like that only when referencing to the previous table first, which means `A join B join C on A.col = C.col on A.col = B.col` would yield an error. This should give you a hint of execution.

Comment: The first is easier to follow and the more typical way to write the `join`s.  They return the same result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an `INNER JOIN` there isn't a difference. The differences is when an `OUTER JOIN` comes into the play.

Let's say you have these tables:

Table A:

```
ID          BID
----------- -----------
1           1
2           NULL
3           2
```

Table B:

```
ID          BVAL
----------- ----------
1           X
2           Y
```

Table C:

```
BID         CVAL
----------- ----------
1           ABC
```

If you then query

```
SELECT * FROM A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B
      ON B.ID = A.ID
   INNER JOIN C
      ON C.BID = B.ID
```

you would get exactly one record:

```
ID          BID         ID          BVAL       BID         CVAL
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
1           1           1           X          1           ABC
```

but this query

```
SELECT * FROM A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B
      INNER JOIN C
         ON C.BID = B.ID
      ON B.ID = A.ID
```

would give three:

```
ID          BID         ID          BVAL       BID         CVAL
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------
1           1           1           X          1           ABC
2           NULL        NULL        NULL       NULL        NULL
3           2           NULL        NULL       NULL        NULL
```

So as you can see, the nested `JOIN` is evaluated before the other.

Comment: I like your example, +1 :-) I think it's worth adding that you can only reference the previous table with the `join join on <here> on ...` which confirms the order of execution

Comment: @KamilG. . . . There is no "order of execution".  Period.  SQL is a declarative language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff we may call it whatever we like, but you know that you can actually steer planner into performing some tasks prior to another. Just create dependency. Don't you agree? How would you call that to better reflect that possibility?

Comment: @KamilG. . . . I call it a *query optimizer*.  The order of the joins in the declaration generally has almost no effect on the actual execution plan.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree in general, but how about this particular case? Doesn't `B join C` need to happen first in order to be able to outer join that to `A`?

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN`s aren't always between *tables*. They're frequently between *previous results of `JOIN`s*. Therefore, join *order* is important.

In the first query, we join table `A` to table `B`. In the first `ON` clause, we may only reference tables `A` or `B`. Lets say this produces a result that we'll informally call `A_B`. The second join then occurs between `A_B` and `C`. The second `ON` clause may contain references to `A`, `B` or `C`, but be clear that the `A` or `B` references are actually references to the `A_B` result produced by the first `JOIN`.

In the second query, we first join table `B` to table `C`. In that first `ON` clause (which is related to the *second* `JOIN` clause), we may only reference tables `B` or `C`. We'll call that result `B_C`. The second `ON` clause then completed the *first* `JOIN`, joining `A` to `B_C` and this second `ON` clause may again reference `A`, `B` or `C`, but this time `B` or `C` are references to `B_C`.<sup>1</sup>

The clearest way to visualize how `JOIN` and `ON` clauses are matched up is to treat `JOIN` the same way as you would an opening parenthesis and `ON` as if it's a closing parenthesis. Then matching parenthesis indicate which `ON`s are matched to which `JOIN` and the nesting tells you what *order* the joins occur in.

---

<sup>1</sup>Though these differences aren't often important when only using `INNER` joins and when each `ON`, in fact, only references one of two tables.

Answer (score 0):

The results will be the same.
If only INNER JOIN is used anyway.

But the first way is the standard and proper way to do it.
It's more readable and less confusing.

How it affects the Explain Plan? That's up to the database.
SQL is a declarative language. Where we ask what we want, not how to pull it out.
*(at least if one doesn't use T-SQL [hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql))*

Here's an example T-SQL to demonstrate that the results are the same.

```
declare @A table (ID_A int, FK_B int);
declare @B table (ID_B int, FK_C int);
declare @C table (ID_C int);
insert into @A (ID_A, FK_B) values (11,21),(12,22),(13,null);
insert into @B (ID_B, FK_C) values (21,null),(22,32),(23,33);
insert into @C (ID_C) values (31),(32),(33);

-- A to B, B to C
select a.ID_A, b.ID_B, c.ID_C
from @A a
inner join @B b on (b.ID_B = a.FK_B)
inner join @C c on (c.ID_C = b.FK_C);

-- (B to C) to A
select a.ID_A, b.ID_B, c.ID_C
from @A a
inner join @B b inner join @C c on (c.ID_C = b.FK_C) 
on (b.ID_B = a.FK_B);
```

Both result in:

```
ID_A ID_B ID_C
---- ---- ----
12   22   32
```